# prop.test alternative usage for differences test

Tags: r, p-value

I have a following matrix `mat` of successes:

```
50 24
46 36
```

and want to perform a 2-sample test for equality significance with `prop.test`. Should I use the all alternative options?

```
prop.test(mat, alternative = "less", correct = FALSE)
prop.test(mat, alternative = "greater", correct = FALSE)
prop.test(mat, alternative = "two.sided", correct = FALSE)
```

Firstly I used just `prop.test(mat, correct = FALSE)` which gives the `two.sided` one, but after just checking the others I found better `p-values`.

Comment: where I meet significant differences in p-values is in this matrix: `mat=matrix(c(50,46,21,36), ncol = 2)`

Comment: There is a distinction between one-sided and two-sided tests. You simply test different things, and hence your p-values are different. This is not so much about "better", more about what your actual hypothesis is. Please have a look at a suitable online-tutorial that explains the difference. There are many out there.

Comment: Don't compute a bunch of tests and *then* pick an alternative you like. What was your actual alternative hypothesis before you ran the test?